# while inside while, stuck at first record

Tags: sql, asp-classic, while-loop, updates

```
        while not rs.eof
            if request("QTY_NOWRECEIVE"&rs("pd_id")) <> "" then
                rsa.movefirst
                if not rsa.eof then
                    if trim(request("stock_id"&rs("pd_id"))) = trim(rsa("stock_id")) and trim(request("ORDER_NUMBER"&rs("pd_id"))) = trim(rsa("PONumber")) then
                        '''check, same then edit record
                        (...)
                        rsa.update
                    else
                        '''check, not same then add record
                        rsa.addnew
                        (...)
                        rsa.update
                    end if
                rsa.movenext
                end if
            end if
        rs.movenext
        wend
```

> now i got 2 sql. sql1 from the form and sql2 from database. First i add new records by form 1, 2 and 3. So database got records 1, 2 and 3. then i edit become 1a, 2b and 3c. but with my result in database is 1a, 2, 3, 1a and 1a. Is my logic totally wrong?

Now I only wan to check did my submit got same item with database. If same then edit, if not same then add new.

19-02-2014
1.add rsa.movefirst. 2.change while not rsa.eof to if not rsa.eof then

Comment: I'm not at all clear on what you're trying to do. If you showed some sample data, your queries, and expected results, we might be able to help. But, I would note that you do nothing to requery `rsa` - so once it's hit `eof` once (which it will do once through the loop), nothing will ever cause `rsa.eof` to be false again, so the inner loop will never run again.

Comment: sorry my English poor. like this : now i got 5 item in my form 1,2,3,4,5. and I add 2,3,4 to database.
now form got 1,2,3,4,5. database got 2,3,4.
then I wish to edit 2,3,4 to 1,2,3,4. but the result is 2,3,4,1,2,3,4.
I'm doing my best to explain it. Sorry again my English poor.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite following your scenario, but I think you need the second recordset, `rsa` to loop every time there is a new record in `rs`, correct?

If so, you need to tell rsa to start over by adding `movefirst`

```
    while not rs.eof
          if (...) then
                 rsa.movefirst
                 while not rsa.eof 
                        if (whatever) then
                               ...
                        else
                               ...   
                               rsa.update
                        end if
                        rsa.movenext
                 wend
          end if
          rs.movenext
   wend
```

If you don't add the MoveFirst, rsa will always be at the last record and will never iterate through the loop again.

Comment: thank you for replying. now I got another problem.  with this code, I get the result like this : in database got records 2,3,4. and I want to change 2,3,4 to 2a,3a,4a. and the result is 2a,3,4,3a,4a. I successes edit the first record but not to the other. Did I miss something?

Comment: There is something wrong with the logic in your IF statement.  OR.  There could be something wrong with the variables that are being passed in over the QueryString.  It's impossible for us to tell without seeing the data.

Comment: Now my loop only always stuck at rsa 1st record. When I want to change 2,3,4 to 2a,3a,4a. and the result is 2a,3,4,3a,4a. It only check the 1st record, so only can edit the 1st record. Another will been add new records. What kind of data you need to see?